# an Error occurred in MPI_Put and getting invalid RMA address

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to learn RMA (remote memory access). the following code is a sample code that I wrote to test the MPI_Put and then I want to use the same approach in my real code.

In this sample code I have a vector of vectors, I want each rank with the rank_ID update the v_a[rank_ID][m].

the code is :

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int pCurrentID, pRightID, pLeftID, tag = 1 , size, value;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pCurrentID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  std::vector<std::vector<double> > v_A;


  int n = 2;
  int m = 5;
  for (int i =0; i<n; i++) {
    v_A[i].resize(m);
  }

  double temp = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      v_A[i][j] = temp;
    }
    temp++;
  }

    MPI_Win win;
    int disp_unit = sizeof(double);
    int size_inner_obj_D = v_A[0].size();
    MPI_Win_create(v_A[0].data(), v_A.size() * size_inner_obj_D * sizeof(double),
                   disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);


   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);
   for(int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
     if (pCurrentID == i) {
     double* buf = new double[m];
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
       buf[i] = i + 1.0;
     }
     MPI_Put(buf, size_inner_obj_D, MPI_DOUBLE, pCurrentID, i * size_inner_obj_D, size_inner_obj_D, MPI_DOUBLE, win);
   }
   }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
       std::cout<<v_A[i][j]<<", "<<std::endl;
     }
   }
   MPI_Win_free(&win);
  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

and the error is :

```
[FK] *** Process received signal ***
[FK] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[FK] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[FK] Failing at address: 0x8
[FK] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff2044dd7d _sigtramp + 29
[FK] [ 1] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20422c46 dyld_stub_binder + 282
[FK] [ 2] 0   ch1                                 0x000000010a939e40 _ZNSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEE6resizeEm + 32
[FK] [ 3] 0   ch1                                 0x000000010a939a6a main + 170
[FK] [ 4] [FK] *** Process received signal ***
[FK] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[FK] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[FK] Failing at address: 0x8
[FK] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff2044dd7d _sigtramp + 29
[FK] [ 1] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20422c46 dyld_stub_binder + 282
[FK] [ 2] 0   ch1                                 0x0000000104838e40 _ZNSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEE6resizeEm + 32
[FK] [ 3] 0   ch1                                 0x0000000104838a6a main + 170
[FK] [ 4] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20423f5d start + 1
[FK] [ 5] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
[FK] *** End of error message ***
0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20423f5d start + 1
[FK] [ 5] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
[FK] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node cecs-064185 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edited:

I also tried to use 1D array for saving this vector of vector:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int pCurrentID, pRightID, pLeftID, tag = 1 , size, value;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pCurrentID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  std::vector<std::vector<double> > v_A;



  int n = 2;
  int m = 5;
  v_A.resize( n );
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      v_A[i].resize(m);
  }


  double temp = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      v_A[i][j] = temp;
    }
    temp++;
  }


double* myArray = new double[n*m];
  double* ptrArray = myArray;
  for (int i =0;i < n; i++) {
    std::copy(v_A[i].begin(), v_A[i].end(), ptrArray);
    ptrArray += v_A[i].size();
  }
if (pCurrentID == 0) {
for (int j=0; j< (m*n); j++) {
  std::cout<<myArray[j]<<" ,";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
}
    MPI_Win win;
    int disp_unit = sizeof(double);
    int size_inner_obj_D = m;
    MPI_Win_create(myArray, n*m * size_inner_obj_D * sizeof(double),
                   disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);


   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);
   for(int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
     if (pCurrentID == i) {
     double* buf = new double[m];
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
       buf[j] = i + 1.0;
     }
     std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" buf : "<<buf[i]<<std::endl;

     MPI_Put(buf, size_inner_obj_D, MPI_DOUBLE, pCurrentID, i * size_inner_obj_D, size_inner_obj_D, MPI_DOUBLE, win);
   }
   }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);
   //
   if (pCurrentID == 0) {
   for (int j=0; j< (m*n); j++) {
     std::cout<<myArray[j]<<" ,";
   }
}
   MPI_Win_free(&win);
  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

the problem is the result is:

```
0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,
i = 0 buf : 1
i = 1 buf : 2
1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1
```

I expected to be :

```
0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,
i = 0 buf : 1
i = 1 buf : 2
1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2
```

I checked the buf it is changed to 2, but why we are not getting them in the print in a right way?

if we are using 1D array in this problem, it is efficient? is there any other way to do that?

Comment: `v_A` is declared as a jagged array (e.g. array of array) but it should be in contiguous memory. `boost.MPI` can help you with `C++` multi-dimensional arrays, or you can simply declare `double v_A[n][m];`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I sent another simple codes, I could run putting just one double but I can't put a vector of 2 doubles!

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet for your answer, what do you mean about boost.MPI, you mean I have allocate a new memory?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I updated the question and used 1D array

Answer (score 0):

I even can't run a vector of 2 doubles as follows:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int pCurrentID, pRightID, pLeftID, tag = 1 , size, value;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pCurrentID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  std::vector<double> v_A;


  int n = 2;
  v_A.resize(2);

  double temp = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      v_A[i] = temp;
    temp++;
  }

    MPI_Win win;
    int disp_unit = sizeof(double);
    MPI_Win_create(&v_A, n * sizeof(double),
                   disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);

   double* buf = new double[n];
   for(int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
     buf[i] = i + 1.0;
   }

    if (pCurrentID == 1) {
   MPI_Put(buf, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, n, MPI_DOUBLE, win);
 }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);
if (pCurrentID == 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       std::cout<<v_A[i]<<", "<<std::endl;

   }

 }
   MPI_Win_free(&win);
  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

but with one double it works:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int pCurrentID, pRightID, pLeftID, tag = 1 , size, value;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pCurrentID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  double v_A;

    MPI_Win win;
    int disp_unit = sizeof(double);
    MPI_Win_create(&v_A, 1 * sizeof(double) ,
                   disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);
   if (pCurrentID == 1) {
      double v_b = 3.0;
      MPI_Put(&v_b, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, win);
   }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win);

   if (pCurrentID == 0) std::cout<<v_A<<", "<<std::endl;
   MPI_Win_free(&win);
  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: try replacing `&v_A` with `v_A.data()`. It works for me but you should really ask a second opinion to someone who knows C++.

Comment: Thank @GillesGouaillardet it works for vector of 2 doubles now, I tried to change it based on your replys and I am still getting errors, (I updated the code of question). I can't understand what should I do if I don't want to change the std::vector<std::vector<double> > v_A;

Comment: If you want to stick to a jagged array, then you have to send one (inner) vector at a time.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am trying to send inner vector each time by each rank